# Reference Constant value in excel pivot table

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, pivot-table

I've encountered an issue with an excel pivot table that I'm hoping someone can assist with.

Scenario: showing a pivot table of missed/failed server backups sorted by quarter and date, also showing the % of each status against the total number of servers in the organization:

My data source table contains the following data:

```
date |  ServerName  | Status(Missed/Failed) |
```

My pivot table organizes the data as such:

```
Qtr1+
   | date | Total missed |  Total Failed  | Total Missed/Failed |
```

I also have a single cell in the report that shows the total number of servers in the organization (We get this value from an outside source). This field is edited by the end user/person running the report.

What I want to achieve in the end is for my pivot table to show the count of each missed/failed field as a percentage AGAINST that constant value. IE to look like this:

```
Qtr1+
    | date | % missed | % Failed  | Total Missed | Total Failed |
```

I have tried to include the total number of servers into the main data source by adding a column at the end of my table to include the total in every row. IE:

```
 date  |  ServerName  | Status(Missed/Failed) | TotalServers |
 apr-1 |   ABC123     |        Missed         |    800       |
 apr-1 |   CBA123     |        Failed         |    800       |
```

However: When I try to include it into the pivot table or using a calculated field, it's summing the total instead of treating it as a unique, unchanging value, thus giving me an incorrect value.

So is there a way to achieve what I want to do with the pivot table? I want to avoid using VBA as much as possible, but I am willing to implement some if I have to. I apologize if any of this comes across as unclear. I will do my best to elaborate on anything.

Answer (score 1):

So, I would probably try changing the value from a SUM to MAX (or MIN in this case since all values are the same) in the "Summarize Value Field By" under value field settings. This essentially just tells the pivot to use the 800 instead of the 800 * number of rows that you have it populated in.

You can get to this value by double-clicking on the header row of the pivot or by clicking on the field item in the Values pane of your field list side-bar menu.

Let me know if that works, but I think that should get you where you want to go.

The above didn't address the calculated column being used for the question asked.

If this is persisting, I would suggest using a unique countIF in your dataset to get a Sum of 800 across some specific criteria being used in the pivot - Assuming that the columns for ServerName is Column B in your dataset:

=800/COUNTIF(B:B,B1)

When you pivot - the calculated field should take the sum of 800 for that server name and apply the miss/fail to the 800 instead of the sum of the total.

Comment: Nope...Although it changes the values in the pivot table, the calculated field remains unchanged. The field is:
` =countOfMis-Fail / servers`

Comment: Okay, that makes it a little more complicated - instead of using the 800 in your data set for every line - I would probably then edit the dataset to be something like 800 / the count of the specific server name using countIF. That way the total SUM for that unique server name will always be 800.

Comment: Nope, still giving me the same results. I've also tried using MIN, MAX and AVERAGE in the calculated field itself IE: FailMiss / AVERAGE(severs) and yet it still provides incorrect data....This seems like such a simple issue that should have an easy solution but I'm stumpped